# Twitter Puppeteer - Google authentication popup

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Hello I want to handle popups in puppeteer and node.js

```
  await page.goto('https://twitter.com');

  await sleep(3000);
  const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.url().startsWith('https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button'));
  const acceptBtn = await frame.$('#container > div > div.nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-bN97Pc-sM5MNb.oXtfBe-l4eHX > span.nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-BPrWId');
  await acceptBtn.click();
```

So scheme is:

1. Go to page.com
2. Click "Sign in via Google"  (here we send click to iframe, code above)
3. New window popup appear, and I wanna send puppeteer actions in this popup

So how to tell puppeteer that he will use this popup as page, or wait it for open, and declare it?

[image]

I was trying do this way, but sadly doesnt work :(

```
  browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => { //
    if (target.type() === 'page') {               // if it tab/page
      const page = await target.page();      // declare it
      const url = page.url();                // example, look at her url
      if (url.search('accounts.google.com/v3/signin') == -1) {     // if url is not like site.com (pop-up window whith ads to anower site)
        await page.close();           // close this page
      }
    }
  });
```

I was trying things from this topic and still can't find fix.
[Puppeteer - Handle basic authentication popup (that appears after clicking on a link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334854/puppeteer-handle-basic-authentication-popup-that-appears-after-clicking-on-a)

Comment: what does does ```const url``` output when you console log it.

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S1192135721%3A1675036748554692&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fgsi%2Fselect%3Fclient_id%3D49625052041-kgt0hghf445lmcmhijv46b715m2mpbct.apps.googleusercontent.com%26ux_mode%3Dpopup%26ui_mode%3Dcard%26as%3DrwIoIcvCoBpIsrsOTd1cuA%26channel_id%3D4989c4cec1e8bcacb0fa3a61d66a4075a6fb0fe6f78b9a33ffb8f478d14f86e6%26origin%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com&faa=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AWnogHf6vnK9o80Idy_u1hZj3YKJ5-A0d-73GtYNNbtXwH99_1ujvEtvFxCXKDJmE63Uivex8yH_nQ

Comment: so it return url of popup

Comment: Ok so that's good then, have you tried to get puppeteer to select any elements on the popup? What happens when you do?

Comment: Weird because now it not return nothing, but everything works same :(

Comment: I rewrote code and it return popup.url(), but when try do action it not doing nothing and not push error.. not sure what is wrong

Comment: Would you be able to link to a github with the code? I want to try it out